# Really simple HTML server for raspberry pi

Tags: raspberrypi, hosting

I'm running Ubuntu mate on my raspberry pi 2 b+ . I want to make it hosting an HTMl file. My problem is that I'm low on ressources. E.g. with my main usage program which runs 24/7 on it, there's no memory left for starting Firefox,  so I need a lightweight solution.
I don't need a complex site, just something that returns this sample.html file if someone accesses http://192.168.178.8 (as sample)

Comment: For fetching the file you can use `wget` and for serving you can program an own webserver, from your profile i see that you can java and c#. You just need to know a little bit of the `http protocol` and of `berkeley sockets` and you can implement a simple web server serving a html file

Comment: Hi, was any of the answers useful to you? If yes, please consider accepting and/or voting up. If you need further help or clarification, then please ask back!

Comment: thanks @Nephente , I'm sorry that I needed more time as  expected to try the answers and get them work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it, that you really just want to read an HTML document on the Raspi, but the system has not enough memory to start its default browser Firefox.

You could try a more lightweight browser like `midori`. Install with

```
sudo apt-get install midori
```

---

If you truly need to serve the pages to the local LAN, you need to install a web-server. `nginx` is resource-wise a good choice.

1. Install it with

   ```
   sudo apt-get install nginx-light nginx-common
   ```

   There is also a `nginx-full` package which brings more functionality, but I don't believe is needed here.

   When the installation is done, the server should start automatically. You can control it with

   ```
   sudo service nginx start/stop/restart/...
   ```

   If you now browse to the address of the Raspi, you will already see a page being served ("Welcome to nginx...")
2. The welcome page you see is served from `/var/www/html`. The configuration is stored in `/etc/nginx`.

   If you are lazy and want a quick fix, simply put your files into this folder. By default a document `index.html` is served. If it does not exist, a document tree will be served instead. The directory contains of course the welcome-page. Move it out of the way first. If you want to serve files from a different folder, read on.

   There exist two directories

   ```
   /etc/nginx/sites-available
   /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
   ```

   The first one holds the actual configuration files, while the second contains links to those configuration sites. These links tell nginx to process the config and serve the site.

For your goal it suffices to adapt the existing configuration a bit.

3. First, delete the symlink to `default`

   ```
   sudo rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
   ```

   so the server will not serve the Welcome page by default.
4. Now copy `default` and alter it

   ```
   cd /etc/nginx/sites-available
   sudo cp default mysite
   ```

   Name it anyway you like better than `mysite`.
5. Open the file with an editor. Most of the setting are fine, but you need to adapt `root` so it points to the directory which contains the files you want to serve. This is basically all you need to do, but one option is quite useful:

   `index`: Which document is served when the document root http://server/ is browsed.
6. Reload the config with

   ```
   sudo service nginx reload
   ```

   and your Pi should serve your webpage!

Answer (score 0):

**nginx** is a lightweight web server, runs well on Raspi

sudo apt-get -y install nginx

Place your default page under /var/www/html

**To configure** edit 
/etc/nginx/nginx.conf

Answer (score 0):

Install package `netcat-openbsd`. With that the following shell script gets you a very simplistic web server that just always returns your `sample.html` for any request.

Note that it can't provide any additional files like images, CSS files or similar.

```
#!/bin/sh

while (
printf "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"
printf "Content-Type: text/html\r\n"
printf "\r\n"
cat /path/to/sample.html
) | nc -l 80 >/dev/null; do echo; done
```

Replace `/path/to/sample.html` with the path of your actual HTTP file.